# Tableau cannot recognize timestamp field in my log file

Tags: tableau-api, type-conversion

I am using Tableau 9.3 to do a preliminary data analysis on one of my log file, the log file is like below:

> "199.72.81.55",01/Jul/1995:00:00:01,/history/apollo/,200,6245,Sat

As you can see, there is a datetime for timestamp

In Tableau, initially it is recognized as a string like below:

[image]

That's fine, I want to make the field into datetime, and Tableau seems failed on it:

[image]

Why? How do I fix it?

Thank you very much.

UPDATED: after applying the formula suggested below, Tableau still cannot recognize the timestamp, here is the screenshot:

[image]

UPDATED AGAIN: after tested by nick, it is confirmed his first script is correct and working on his Tableau, why it fails on mine, I don't know, you are welcome to share any clue please, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau implicit conversions are limited to more standard formats. You can still create a `DATETIME` field from your timestamp string using a calculated field with the following formula:

`DATEPARSE('dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss',[timestamp])`

Using the above will transform a string like `01/Jul/1995:00:00:01` to a date and time of `7/1/1995 12:00:01 AM`

Output using example data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, still showing null, I've updated the OP to post the screenshot

Comment: Are there any spaces following the timestamp value in your dataset? It will return a null if not all characters are accounted for

Comment: No, there is no trailing space, I've double checked the raw csv file. and I also tried this: `DATE (LEFT([timestamp],2) + "/" + MID([timestamp],3,3) + "/" + MID([timestamp],7,3))`

Comment: What happens when you do something like this (ignore the time)?: `DATEPARSE('dd/MMM/yyyy',LEFT([timestamp],11))` Does that work? (This is just to test - I know you still need the time)

Comment: Can we go chatting?http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/121104/tableau-calculated-filed?tab=general

Comment: Sure, I am in there now

Comment: I don't see you, here is a new chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121105/room-for-mdivk-and-nicarus

Comment: I can see your messages but am unable to write back. Possibly blocked some portion the chat here at my work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the "date parse" function in Tableau doesn't quite do the job.

When this happens it is worth testing manual string manipulation with your timestamp field to put it into ISO-standard format and only then trying to convert it into a date. ISO format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (eg 2012-02-28 13:04:30). It is common to find that the original string has spurious characters or spaces that throw dateparse. But these are usually easy to manipulate away with suitable text manipulations. This can sometimes be longwinded, but it always works.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the region setting issue, it works after I switch it to USA